# about asynchronous execution flow in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

good, I come to ask what would be the best way to make the task of showing a Mysql data taken

¿Think this flow is correct?

```
app.get('/demo/:id', function(req, res) {

 var query = csql.query('SELECT * FROM table_videos WHERE id=? LIMIT 1',req.params.id,
 function(error, result){
     if(error){
         datos_video = error;
     }else{
         if (result.length) {
             datos_video = result[0];
         }else{
             datos_video = '0';
         }
     }
 });

 res.render('vid',{datos_video:datos_video});

});
```

The render is executed after or before your consultation?

Maybe it's better to do something

```
app.get('/demo/:id', function(req, res) {

 var query = csql.query('SELECT * FROM table_videos WHERE id=? LIMIT 1',req.params.id,
 function(error, result){
     if(error){
         datos_video = error;

         res.render('vid',{datos_video:datos_video});

     }else{
         if (result.length) {
             datos_video = result[0];

             res.render('vid',{datos_video:datos_video});

         }else{
             datos_video = '0';

            res.render('vid',{datos_video:datos_video});

         }
     }
 });


});
```

What is the correct way? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way is right.

The first way might work, but it probably won't and you can't garuntee it. If you want to ensure Syncronous execution in JavaScript, it is always best to make use of callback functions, like you did in the second example.